# Running a Cassandra pod in Kubernetes as Cassandra user volume mount fails

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, kubernetes-helm

I'm creating a StatefulSet for Cassandra in kubernetes, here is my statefulset.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Values.name }}
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.secretName }}
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Values.name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.cassandra.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.cassandra.image.tag}}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.cassandra.image.pullPolicy }}
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
            runAsNonRoot: true
            runAsUser: 999 # 999 = the cassandra user within the cassandra container
            runAsGroup:
            seccompProfile:
              type: RuntimeDefault
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - "ALL"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: {{ .Values.name }}-data
              mountPath: {{ .Values.persistence.podPath }}
          ports:
          - containerPort: {{ .Values.service.port }}
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "{{ .Values.resources.requests.memory }}"
              cpu: "{{ .Values.resources.requests.cpu }}"
            limits:
              memory: "{{ .Values.resources.limits.memory }}"
              cpu: "{{ .Values.resources.limits.cpu }}"
          env:
            - name: CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME
              value: "{{ .Values.cassandra.clusterName }}"
            - name: CASSANDRA_DC
              value: "{{ .Values.cassandra.datacenterName }}"
            - name: CASSANDRA_SEED_SERVICE_NAME
              value: "{{ .Values.cassandra.seedNodeServiceName }}"
#      volumes:
#      - name: {{ .Values.name }}-data
#        persistentVolumeClaim:
#          claimName: {{ .Values.name }}-pvc
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: {{ .Values.name }}-data
      spec:
        accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi
```

But if I try to mount (so podPath) to /var/lib/cassandra, the pod encounters this error:

```
ERROR [main] 2023-11-29 00:01:09,025 CassandraDaemon.java:883 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:253)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:726)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:861)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: /opt/cassandra/data/data; unable to start server
        at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.createAllDirectories(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1866)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<init>(CommitLog.java:108)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.construct(CommitLog.java:92)
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLog.<clinit>(CommitLog.java:77)
        ... 3 common frames omitted
```

I can get the pod to work if I just mount a path like `/opt/cassandra/data`, but then if I delete the pod, no data will actually persist

Removal of the securityContext: values is not possible unfortunately